# Yefas Toar - rape allowed by the Torah before the marriage?

Tags: reward-punishment, army-military-war, beauty

[Ki Saitzai](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.21.10?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) deals with the Eishes Yefas Toar “woman of beautiful form” taken in battle.

[Ramban and Rabbeinu Tam](https://www.ou.org/life/torah/brander_ki_teitzei_5768_the_battle/#fn4)   say that the Torah permits the soldier to have relations with the maiden immediately. After that the Torah requires a thirty day procedure of stripping the maiden of her allure before she can be married to her captor.

So it seems that the Yefas Toar can be made to have relations with her captor immediately without consent. Why is she treated in this way; we do not find rape as allowed in the Torah elsewhere?

This question is additional to the [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81689/how-is-yefas-toar-fair-to-the-woman) about the justice of the thirty day procedure.

Comment: Punishment for what? Where do you see it's a punishment?

Comment: Is it done with consent??

Comment: A consensual captive?

Comment: Are you claiming this is "punishment" any more than anything that happens to a losing army in battle?

Comment: Thank you for the comments on punishment. I have removed the cooncept from the question.